# Bootstrap 4 npm package comes with a dist/ different from what is compiled from its scss/?

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4

npm package.json  `"bootstrap": "^4.1.1",`

```
node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;  // note this line
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;  // note this line
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}
```

Corresponding line in scss is

```
node_modules/bootstrap/scss/_grid.scss
.row {
  @include make-row();
}
```

make-row mixin is from

```
node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins/_grid.scss
@mixin make-row() {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: ($grid-gutter-width / -2);
  margin-left: ($grid-gutter-width / -2);
}
```

---

## Difference

These two lines are not in the mixin, and you will not see them in the css compiled from the scss source.

```
display: -ms-flexbox;
-ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
```

---

## Observations

1. Diff your compiled css to the css in package dist/, you will see 95% of the diff lines are missing lines related to flex.
2. `node_modules/bootstrap/scss` just does not contain any string of 'ms-flex'.
3. Because of the missing flex lines, [this kitchen sink](https://codepen.io/JacobLett/pen/KaMoEm) fails on IE10 when using self-compiled css -- Grid, Media Object and everything about left-right flow.  It looks good on codepen because it uses CDN dist/ css
4. I need to customize bootstrap, eg change primary color, and build it by myself.

---

## Question

How to make self-compiled css same as the one in dist/?

Info: I use [`gulp-compass`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-compass) to compile.

Comment: You need to compile using an `autoprefixer`

Comment: The attributes that start with `-` are vendor prefixes, to ensure browser compatibility. They are added to Bootstrap during the build using a NPM package called "Autoprefixer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Bootstrap uses an `autoprefixer` module (and your compiler routine don't) so each specific vendor prefix is added to the `css` automatically. For example, if you use: `display: flex;` the prefix for Internet Explorer 11 will be added automatically: `display: -ms-flexbox;`. The autoprefixer will add all the vendor prefixes for all the properties that needs one, automatically.

It's a good practice, so you don't have to bother about remembering all the prefixes for all the different browser. You can find autoprefixers for almost every compiler out there.

In your case you could use the `gulp-autoprefixer` npm package ([more info](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-autoprefixer)).

You should install the package first by running the following command: `npm install --save-dev gulp-autoprefixer`; then you should add a few modifications to your `Gulpfile.js`:

1. Load the autoprefixer module: `var prefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');`.
2. Pipe it: `.pipe(prefixer())` to your current `bootstrap` compiling piping.

You can pass your desired target browsers as autoprefixer params, for example: `prefixer({ browsers: ['last 2 versions', 'ie >= 10'] })`, to match last 2 versions of browsers and Internet Explorer version 10 or latter.

Hope it helps.